# Defined Integral of a function defined by parts

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The function is the following:

[image]

The objetive of the exercise is to calculate
[image].

For that I used the following steps:

[image]

My resolution is wrong because the result has to be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have two calculations wrong.  The biggest problem is that, even though at x = 1, y = 2, this is an *infinitesimal* point.  Therefore, it has no bearing whatsoever on the integral.  If y was equal to 2 for some period of time (like 0.8 > x > 1.2), then it would have an effect.  But, for the infinitely small slice of time where x = 1, y isn't 2 long enough to make any difference.  Therefore, you can treat it as just an ordinary integral of $x\,dx$ from 0 to 2.

The other problem you did is that, when you split up the integral into two pieces, you did the right hand one wrong.

$$\int_1^2 x\,dx = \frac{x^2}{2} \biggr\rvert_1^2 = \frac{2^2}{2} - \frac{1^2}{2} = \frac{4}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$$

When added to your first one, you would get 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Johnny!

Answer (score 2):

An integral from $a$ to $b$ isn’t simply the sum of $f(x)$ for each $x\in[a,b]$, but instead the sum of $f(x) dx$ (times an infinitesimal) for each $x\in[a,b]$. So, when you’re dividing the integral into parts, you should get:

$$\int_0^2 g(x) dx = \int_0^1 x dx + g(1) dx + \int_1^2 x dx $$ and $g(1) dx \to 0$ so it can be neglected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tavish!

Comment: @TiagoGonçalves You’re very welcome

Comment: Is this a generalization for every problem which has a defined function as in the previous mentioned form?

Comment: @TiagoGonçalves Certainly, this is what an integral means.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{blue}{g(x)=2 \text{ when } x = 1}$ doesn't mean $\color{red}{g(x)=2 \text{ when } x\in[1,2](\text{or some other intervals with length 1})}$.

And recall the definition of the integral.

Comment: Thank you for your answer FFjet!